# Understanding the FTSE Actuaries Share Indices on the Financial Times Paper UK

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, financial-literacy, stock-markets

I am trying to understand how to read the Financial Times FTSE Actuaries Share Indices UK. In two of the columns it says Cover and Exadj. Cover is between Dividend Yield % and P/E ratio. Exadj is located between P/E ratio and total returns.

Does anybody know what Cover and Xdadj means?

I have attached a link for people to have a look at.

http://markets.ft.com/RESEARCH/markets/DataArchiveFetchReport?Type=FTUK

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be [dividend coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividend_cover), which is the ratio of earnings to dividend amount.

The formula (using other items from the report) would be `1 / (Div Yield/100 * P/E ratio)`